# RequestNavigate a view *away* from an ItemsControl Region

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, region

I'm working on a WPF application based on the Microsoft Prism framework.  One aspect of the application uses an `ItemsControl` region.  I can add views to the `ItemsControl` by `RequestNavigate`-ing a view to the region.  However, I don't see a way to `RequestNavigate` *away* from the region, i.e. so that the view is removed from the region and the "OnNavigatedFrom" callback is fired in the view's ViewModel.

The only way I've seen to remove a view from an `ItemsControl` region is to manually remove the view from the region like so:

```
IRegion myRegion = _regionManager.Regions["MyRegion"];
myRegion.Remove(viewToRemove);
```

This won't work for me, unfortunately, because I need the `OnNavigatedTo` and `OnNavigatedFrom` callbacks to be fired when the view is added to/removed from the region.

Am I missing something?  Is there a way to `RequestNavigate` a view *away* from a region?

Comment: What would happen if you could navigate away in a Region? Would you want the Region to have no Active Views or would you like the previous View become active? The main question would be why you don't want to Navigate to other View. Regards.

Comment: @GOstrowsky From my understanding, all views currently in the region have their `IsActive` property set to `true`.  So ideally a `RequestNavigateFrom` method would remove the view from the region, set `IsActive` to false, and fire the `OnNavigatedFrom` callback.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "why you don't want to Navigate other View."  Navigating to another view in an `ItemsControl` region just adds the view to the region; it doesn't remove or replace an existing view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, you would not need to execute ***OnNavigatedTo/From*** methods if you would not be navigating to a particular *View*.

Anyway, if you may need to execute the ***OnNavigatedFrom()*** implementation before removing the *View* from the *ItemsControl*, you could manually invoke it right before manually removing the *View*.

You could pass null to the ***NavigationContext*** argument if you would not need it, which I believe you don't, or you could manually create it otherwise. The solution would be as follows:

```
INavigationAware viewModel = viewToRemove.DataContext;
viewModel.OnNavigatedFrom(null);
IRegion myRegion = _regionManager.Regions["MyRegion"];
myRegion.Remove(viewToRemove);
```

I hope this helped you.

Comment: Thanks, GOstrowsky, this lead me in the right direction.